# Syntax error trying to use a variable in my query on a remote server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, linked-server

I want to query MySql database in MSSQL using linked server however I keep getting this error: 
***Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure uspGetTimeLog, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near '+'.***

Here is the sql code below

```
 SELECT * FROM  OPENQUERY([MYSQLCONN], 
        'SELECT e_id, TDate, Entry, `Exit` FROM timemgt.daymaster 
        WHERE TDate >= ''''' + @frmDate + ''''' ')
```

This is working

```
SELECT * FROM  OPENQUERY([MYSQLCONN], 
    'SELECT e_id, TDate, TIME_FORMAT(Entry, ''%T'') AS ''Entry'', 
    TIME_FORMAT(`Exit`, ''%T'') AS ''Exit'' FROM timemgt.daymaster 
    WHERE TDate >= ''2017-01-01'' AND TDate <= ''2017-01-01''')
```

This is not working

```
DECLARE @frmDate VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @toDate VARCHAR(10)
SET @frmDate = '2017-01-01'
SET @toDate = '2017-01-01'

SELECT * FROM  OPENQUERY([MYSQLCONN], 
    'SELECT e_id, TDate, TIME_FORMAT(Entry, ''%T'') AS ''Entry'', 
    TIME_FORMAT(`Exit`, ''%T'') AS ''Exit'' FROM timemgt.daymaster 
    WHERE TDate >=''' + @frmDate + ''' AND TDate <= '''+ @toDate +'''')
```

Error am getting

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9 Incorrect syntax near '+'.

There after I will pass it to a temporary table

Comment: 5 single quotes before the + and after the next one - that seems a strange amount.

Comment: what do you mean with ''''' (5 single quotes)  ???? explain your goal

Comment: 3 quotes should be enough.  5 is too much.

Comment: 5 is right out!

Comment: Basically I want to create a stored procedure in MSSQL that will take a parameter @frmDate and will make use of that parameter in MYSQL query.

Comment: Why the end has 4 quotes???

Comment: Not sure better had some quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do similar things, but not with MySQL.  However, I suspect it will work with MySQL as well.

Instead of this:

```
WHERE TDate >= ''''' + @frmDate + '''''
```

you want something like this:

```
WHERE TDate >= ' + @frmDateString + '
```

where `@frmDateString` is a string in this format.

> {ts 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss'}

You will have to experiment with the number of quotes.  I also do things a bit different than you.  My technique is:

```
declare @sql as nvarchar(max);
set @sql = 'select * from openquery(
SERVERNAME,
''
select etc
where SomeDateField > = ' + @dateString + '
etc
''
)
';

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

The significance is that my method requires more single quotes.

Also significant is that I use a scalar function to convert my dates to the properly formatted strings.

**Edit starts here**

I read the comment about the stored procedure after posting this answer.  You will want to use my method.